# MSBuild does not publish VS2013

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to build and publish using MSBuild on VS 2013 environment. When I use

MSBUILD myproject.sln /p:DeployOnBuild /p:PublishProfile=Test

it is building but not publishing. Tried all the options available in different threads, none helped.

When I publish from VS 2013 GUI (Solution Explorer->Right click on project->Publish Web App) it works fine.

Any direction will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing DeployOnBuild to /p:DeployOnBuild=true